# Synonym for "its right up my alley": "It's within my ____"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms

the word you use when you say "its right up my alley"

e.g

its inside my _______.

it means collection of interest or
range of interest.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I'm not sure there's enough information here. Have you looked anything up yourself? What words is it *not*? Do you know about the [online Reverse Dictionary](https://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml?s=range%20of%20interest)? Are any of the words there what you want? Click *purview:* how about those synonyms?

Comment: Your question should include more details and clarify the problem. Do you want a formal or informal word - is it business or casual? Who are you saying this to, and why? What sort of "interest" is this. *As an aside "inside* is unlikely to be correct except in the most formal of circumstances - I would expect "*it is within...*"

Answer (score 7):

A term heard often in sports is "it's right in his ***[wheelhouse](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wheelhouse)***", which the source (TFD) defines as:

> In, related to, or matching someone's general interests, abilities, or
> area of familiarity; in someone's comfort zone.

Comment: "it's right in his wheelhouse" seems to be an American English expression taken from baseball. I have never heard it in British English -> *Baseball broadcasters on radio could be dramatic and talky, but their adjectives were quite scholarly. Oh, they'd talk about a batter trying to get a pitch in his "wheelhouse" or the "southpaw slants" of a pitcher, or of saying "laying the lumber.* "I Hid it Under the Sheets: Growing Up with Radio" Gerald Eskenazi 2005

Comment: The earliest reference I have found is 1986: *Baseball's 50 Greatest Games*  - Page 23 by Bert Randolph Sugar - *Now , as Maz bisected the plate with his bat , at one and the same time calling for a pitch right there in his wheelhouse *

Comment: The cricketing equivalent is probably 'hitting zone', but here's at least one Brit who's going to make use of '[right] in X's wheelhouse'.

Comment: @Greybeard - I first heard this perhaps 15 years ago, oddly enough in relation to boxing, and since then it's popped up in non sports-related areas as well.